# Excitation energy in the free-fermion description of TFIM

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

The transverse-field Ising model has a gapped phase when the field is large and a gapless phase when the field is small. In the gapped phase the gap grows linearly with the field.

One of the ways to solve the model is to use Jordan-Wigner and Bogoliubov transformations to map it into a free fermion model,
$$H = \sum_{k}\epsilon_k (\gamma_k^\dagger\gamma_k + 1/2)$$
where the dispersion is given by
$$\epsilon_k=2(J^2 + h^2 - 2 h J \cos{k})^{1/2}$$
where $J$ is the nearest-neighbor ising coupling and $h$ is the transverse field. See: http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/fs13/cft/SM_Molignini.pdf.

This correctly reproduces the linear dispersion for the gapped phase. But you cannot use this formula in the gapless phase, it gives also a linear relation (see plot). So what is the logic? Does the mapping to free fermions only work in the gapped phase? How do you conclude that for $h<J$ you are in the gapless phase from the fermion description?

[image]

Comment: But the transverse-field Ising chain is **not** gapless in the ordered phase, only at the critical field; see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse-field_Ising_model).

Comment: @Anyon oh I see, so there are degenerate ground states in the ordered phase but the first excited state still has energy $$2|J|(1-|g|)$$ above those ground states?

Comment: Exactly. That is, there is a gap to local excitations, which can be interpreted as the physical gap. While there are two degenerate ground states, one of them is selected by spontaneous symmetry breaking in the thermodynamic limit. To obtain both ground states in the Jordan-Wigner formalism requires [some care](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362968/49107).